# Django Formset Gets Everything from Database

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I need to create a form that allows users to add rows.

models.py:

```
class SocialURL(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    platform= models.ForeignKey('Platform', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.link}"
```

forms.py:

```
class LinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialURL
        fields = ['platform','link']
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def my_formset_view(request):
    activeuser = request.user.id
    response = None
    formset_class = modelformset_factory(
        model=SocialURL, fields=('platform', 'link'), extra=0, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = formset_class(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(commit=False)
            formset.user_id = activeuser
            formset.save()
            response = redirect(to='profiles:home')
    else:
        formset = formset_class()
    if response is None:
        response = render(
            request, 'profiles/social_form.html', dict(formset=formset))
    return response
```

I tried a couple of solutions I found here. I created a formset and it's working, however, it's pulling everything I have in the database, even other users' links.

[image: how my template looks]

If I click on submit, it saves all of these links for the active user as well. How can I make it pull only the active user's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you are not give correct `Queryset` in init?

```
queryset=SocialURL.objects.filter(user_id = activeuser.id))
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = formset_class(data=request.POST, queryset=queryset)
        ...
    else:
        formset = formset_class(queryset=queryset)
        ...
```

More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory